# How to merge / combine the list element in Python

Tags: python

### Combine list elements

I'm working on python list and ran into a problem. I have a list of tuple.

```
oldlist= [('A', 30), ('B', 20), ('A', 10), ('B', 20), ('C', 20), ('D', 10), ('B', 40)]
```

How can I merge them and add up the number regarding to their letter. For example, total A score is 30 + 10 = 40
B score is 20 + 20 + 40 = 80
... so on and so on.

I want my new list looks like this

```
newlist = [('A', 40),('B', 80),('C',20),('D',10)]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I create an new empty list, then add each individual character into it. My goal is to have a list of unique character. 
temp_list = [(A),(B),(C),(D)]
Then I loop through the old list using temp_list item. Then I will add everything up if the value in oldlist match with the Item in my temp_list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in oldlist:
    my_dict[i[0]] = my_dict.get(i[0], 0) + i[1]
output = list(my_dict.items())
```

gives

```
[('A', 40), ('B', 80), ('C', 20), ('D', 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a dictionary, like so:

```
dictionary = {}
for element in oldlist:
    if element[0] in dictionary:
        dictionary[element[0]] += element[1]
    else:
        dictionary[element[0]] = element[1]
```

If you need it in a list, add this:

```
newlist = list(dictionary.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
oldlist= [('A', 30), ('B', 20), ('A', 10), ('B', 20), ('C', 20), ('D', 10), ('B', 40)]
newlist = [(x, sum(list(zip(*y))[1])) for x, y in groupby(sorted(oldlist, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))]
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[('A', 40), ('B', 80), ('C', 20), ('D', 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this may be useful.

```
oldlist= [('A', 30), ('B', 20), ('A', 10), ('B', 20), ('C', 20), ('D', 10), ('B', 40)]
def results(results_list):
    result_dict = {}
    for name, mark in results_list:
        result_dict[name] = result_dict.get(name, 0) + mark
    return list(result_dict.items())

print(results(oldlist))
```

The output is,

```
[('A', 40), ('B', 60), ('C', 20), ('D', 10)]
```